Is the 'My Little Pony Roleplaying Game' the same as Tails of Equestria?
Tails of Equestria is a TTRPG released in 2017 based on the 4th Generation of My Little Pony. Today I discovered that there is a new game available, presumably released in 2023, simply called My little Pony Roleplaying Game. It is still based on the same generation of the show, but its descriptions make no references at all to Tails of Equestria, just stating that is an RPG based on the series. The art looks fairly similar and some chapters you can see in preview images also do. I couldn't find any information online other than websites where you can buy the books, no Wikipedia page or anything similar.
So I'm wondering what this new game and its relation to Tails of Equestria are: Is this just a new release of Tails of Equestria with a different name? Is it like a 2nd edition of the game? Or is this an entirely new RPG for the MLP license?

It's a completely new My Little Pony game
According to this Reddit post:

[...] My Little Pony Roleplaying Game is a slightly more complicated game, and uses base mechanics that are similar to the d20 system [...]. Tails of Equestria, the older MLP RPG by River Horse Games, is a simpler system.

Based on an existing framework

You see, the Essence20 system was developed to be used with GI Joe, Power Rangers, and Transformers RPGs. It was later applied to My Little Pony. The system wasn’t made for My Little Pony.

It's way closer to D&D than the old game

If you’re looking for a system that is primarily a D&D like d20 system, like RPGs with more detailed mechanics and a structured system, [...] the Essence20 system in the My Little Pony Roleplaying game from Renegade Games is your best choice.

But the old game still has its charms

If you looking for a non-d20 based system, like games that are more flexible mechanically, or you want something that [is] more custom fitted to My Little Pony, I’d recommend the older Tails of Equestria from River Horse Games. It’s cheaper and there are more resources available for it, too.

